# Cannot remove directory from Git history

Tags: git

We have a few projects with a public/uploaded directory that clients use to store images/pdfs/etc., which exists in each project repo (added as we just moved to/are learning git) that I now wish to add to the .gitignore.

I'm trying to remove the directory in a single project in the 'develop' branch as a test.

The command I'm using:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch public/uploaded"
```

Generates output as such:

```
rm 'public/uploaded/image_1.jpg'
rm 'public/uploaded/image_2.jpg'
rm 'public/uploaded/image_3.jpg'
rm 'public/uploaded/image_4.jpg'
rm 'public/uploaded/image_5.jpg'
```

Yet ends with:

```
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/develop' is unchanged
```

How come this command is not working, and how can I successfully remove the directory from the history, yet retain the files before adding to .gitignore?

Comment: Note that git does not track directories. Once you remove all files from certain directory, it would automatically disappear from git. In other words, it is impossible in git to track empty directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to combine `--cached`, which operates on the index, with --tree-filter, which uses the working directory.

Try

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch public/uploaded"
```

You may also want to consider adding "--prune-empty".

Comment: Thanks. This has worked. Is this because --tree-filter checks out or commits the working directory, putting the current existing files in that directory into the old commits?

Comment: I believe tree-filter commits the state of your working directory, which was unchanged in your original example.  If you remove the '--cached' it would have worked too, but the index filter form is significantly faster than a tree filter.